# Oracle Apex DA False action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a Dynamic action on Submit button.
So the dynamic action is fired when the Submit button is pressed.

It has a server side condition similar to: `If EMP_CODE <> PROMO_EMP_CODE THEN RETURN FALSE`

Now If its true I have Execute JS as True action which displays message which asks to confirm to proceed.

But if server side condition fails, I want it to display another message that says: `"The EMPCODE needs to match with the PROMO_EMPCODE which is :P1_PRO_EMP_CODE"`

Cn i do this using False DA action?

Comment: Yes, create false event dynamic action.

Comment: I thought you need client-side execution in order to define action for FALSE

Comment: What is the serverside condition on - the dynamic action or the true action ?

Comment: There is no server side condition on true action. Do I need to have one there?

Comment: The server side condition mentioned in question is on the main dynamic action. Then when it branches to true there is execute JS do display the confirm message. If thr server side fails I need to display a different message. How can that be achieved?

Comment: The serverside condition is on DA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server side condition is evaluated at page render time. That means in will not take into account any values entered on the screen on submit.

So if `If EMP_CODE <> PROMO_EMP_CODE THEN RETURN FALSE` yields true *at render time*, the dynamic action will exist. If it yields false... the dynamic action will not be included in your rendered page.

It sounds as if you do not need a dynamic action, but traditional page processing

- Button action: page submit
- Validation to check if "EMPCODE matches PROMO_EMPCODE "

Dynamic actions are not the best way to do form validations

--update--

That is how apex currently works. Dynamic actions happen on the client side, validations happen on the server side in the processing section. Once processing starts, no user interaction is possible anymore. It is very complex to do validations in dynamic actions, as you are experiencing. I'd suggest you rethink the flow of the actions. You'd not be the first with a huge coding mess that is the result of a non-optimal flow.

Now, can you do it ? Yes of course. Is it easy and maintainable ? No.

Here is one way to do it. It is high level and untested, but you should get the point.

1. Create a page item P1_VALIDATION_PASSED.
2. Create a dynamic action on submit

   - Create true action of type pl/sql code that sets the value of P1_VALIDATION_PASSED to Y or N (items to return should be set to P1_VALIDATION_PASSED). Code would be something like:

```
DECLARE
  empcode NUMBER(20);
  prom_emp_code NUMBER(20);
BEGIN
  Select emp_code into empcode from employees where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;
  Select p_emp_code into prom_emp_code from promoted_employees where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;
  IF empcode !=p_emp_code THEN
    :P1_VALIDATION_PASSED := 'N';
  ELSE
    :P1_VALIDATION_PASSED := 'Y';
  END IF;
END;
```

- Create a true action of type confirmation to display the confirmation box. Add a client side condition of type P1_VALIDATION_PASSED = Y
- Create a true action of type page submit. Add a client side condition of type P1_VALIDATION_PASSED = Y
- Create a true action of type alert to display the error message ""The EMPCODE needs to match with the PROMO_EMPCODE which is :P1_PRO_EMP_CODE". Add a client side condition of type P1_VALIDATION_PASSED = N

Comment: IF I keep the DA like earlier-> On click of Submit button, there's a DA which will dispaly confirmation message. Then on same button i add validation as mentioned above. The problem is, the button DA executes first and display's confirmation message.. Then when i click ok, it goes to validation. I want validation to happen first. if ok then proceed to confirmation message

Comment: Thanks Koen. Just one small question, where do i add this code condition?In the last true action where P1_VALIDATION_PASSED=N?-> If EMP_CODE <> PROMO_EMP_CODE THEN RETURN FALSE

Comment: Updated answer with code from your last question. Try to post each question with full info. The statement "If EMP_CODE <> PROMO_EMP_CODE THEN RETURN FALSE" has no meaning for anyone not reading your other questions.